# Spacemacs: Helm-swoop with current-prefix-arg default value

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'd like to change the Spacemacs `SPC s s` key to show multiple lines as default. I found that helm-swoop used `current-prefix-arg`.

For instance, When I run `SPC s s`, I'd like to run this command: `C-u 3 M-x helm-swoop`.

So I can write a function that wrapped the original and added the default value to it.

But I can't rebind the `SPC s s` to use my function.

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Edit:

1) Update the keys

2)
Finally, I found this solution:

```
    (defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
      (cl-defun contextual-helm-swoop (&key $query $source ($multiline (or current-prefix-arg 3)))
        (interactive)
        (helm-swoop :$query $query :$source $source :$multiline $multiline))

      (spacemacs/set-leader-keys
      "ss"    'contextual-helm-swoop)

    )
```

Comment: Part of your problem might be that `SPC-s-s` isn't valid `kbd` syntax for Emacs, as far as I know.  If you mean "press space, then s, then s", you want `SPC s s`.  If you mean "press a chord of super and space, then s", you want `s-SPC s`.  If you mean "shift-space, then s", you want `S-SPC s`.  In all cases, you can use `C-h k` (`describe-key`) to look up how to write a particular key combination.

Comment: yes, you are right. I meant about `SPC s s` instead of `SPC-s-s`. I updated the question.